# How to create a set of data-frames based on a loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I need to create as many copies of the same df with as names of those data-frames changing values stored in a vector. 
For example:

```
z <- c("A-1", "B-2", "C-2", ...)

for (i in z) {
   i <- already_existing_df
  }
```

Manual hard-coding would be something like:

```
`A-1` <- df
`B-2` <- df
# ...and so on
```

Of course I would want to automate this, and not hardcode it... also 'cause it will change every month, and we are talking about many dfs...

Now, I know that to pass `i` as a variable name, you can simply do:

```
df[i]
```

but I don't know how to pass `i` as a `df` name.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach could be using `replicate` to repeat the dataframe `length(z)` times and assign the names to the list

```
z <- c("A-1", "B-2", "C-2")
list_df <- setNames(replicate(length(z), df, simplify = FALSE), z)
```

You can then keep list of dataframes as it is or make them as separate dataframe.

```
list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your desired result you could define a list (or an Environment):

```
z <- vector("list", 3)

for (i in seq_along(z)) {
  z[[i]] <- already_existing_df
}

names(z) <- c("A-1", "B-2", "C-2")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `assign(df, z)` which will assign `df` to your enviroment under the `i` element of `z`.

Comment: Either I don't understand how to do this, or it does not work, I tried both in a loop than by itself. When in a loop it returns:
`Error in z[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: I misread your code, I understood that `i` was an index in the list but it’s an element of `z` so this should be better.